# Error loading yelp dataset to postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to import the Yelp data from their sql file into a postgreSQL 10 database on Windoes by running the code:

```
psql -U postgres yelp_db < yelp_sql
```

and getting the errors below. As you can see it is probably due to the `` ` `` character. Is there any way to easy fix that? The file is 7.3GB so I'd like to avoid having to read it line by line to change the `` ` `` character to `'`.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PaxHeader"
LINE 1: PaxHeader/yelp_db.sql17 uid=998889796
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `yelp_db` /*!40100 ...
                                                 ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USE"
LINE 1: USE `yelp_db`;
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attribute`;
                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
```

Comment: you seem to use mysql syntax against postgres (backquotes and `USE`) - It won't work

Comment: A backtick is invalid in an identifier in SQL (and Postgres). So the only way to fix that broken script is to replace all those dreaded backticks (you could use `sed` for an efficient stream processing). But as that is apparently a SQL script for MySQL that won't probably be the only thing you need to fix.

Comment: humm there is only one file on the website and they say it works on mySql and postgreSQL